# Do split Ochre Jellies get reduced damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

According to the Ochre Jelly's entry, slashing damage splits it into two smaller jellies with half hp

> Split: When a jelly that is Medium or larger is subjected to lightning or slashing damage, it splits into two new jellies if it has at least 10 hit points. Each new jelly has hit points equal to half the original jelly's, rounded down. New jellies are one size smaller than the original jelly.

I've been looking through the rules and can't find if there's any connection between damage and size, other than that small creatures can't use heavy weapons or that large creatures use two handed in one hand (I think).

Are there any rules regarding size reduction's effects on weapon usage and damage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no general rule linking size and damage.  If an effect which causes size change also affects weapon damage, the specific rule for that effect will say so (e.g. the *Enlarge/Reduce* spell).

As the ochre jelly's "Split" reaction says nothing about its damage being modified, it does indeed become twice as dangerous once sliced in half.

Comment: ouch it sounds way too powerful for its CR if you don't have a dedicated knowledge wizard or a lot of foreshadowing/hints (to know that the rogue and fighter either have to get a new weapon or that the wizard has to prepare an AoE spell of the highest spell level)

Comment: @Teco Jellies are *so* slow that while a party might well have someone incapacitated the first time they tangle with one, they'll always be able drag their downed comrade away as they retreat.  The rematch later on with lessons learned in-game will be all the more dramatic and satisfying.